# Pre Authorizing method stack

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

When calling a Pre-Authorized method within another method, is it better to add `@PreAuthorize` to the caller or should we call it using Spring `applicationContext`. I saw the second way in an example. The code snippets follow, which of them is better and why?

**Method 1**

```
@PreAuthorize(...)
public List<String> methodA(args) {

}

@PreAuthorize(...)
public List<String> methodB(args, extraArgs) {
    List<String> aList = methodA(args);

    // Modify aList

    return aList;
}
```

**Method 2**

```
@PreAuthorize(...)
public List<String> methodA(args) {

}

// This will be authorized when we call methodA
public List<String> methodB(args, extraArgs) {
    ThisClass springProxy = applicationContext.getBean(ThisClass.class);
    List<String> aList = springProxy.methodA(args);

    // Modify aList

    return aList;
}
```

Comment: If `methodA` and `methodB` are in the same class the first method doesn't work. This is due to the way how Spring AOP works (using proxies) then you need to use the second method (or inject a reference to the same object).

Comment: Correct. But, in 1st method `methodB` also has the `@PreAuthorize`annotation, so the authorization happens. Is it wrong to do it that way?

Comment: No it isn't but the `@PreAuthorize` on the other method isn't adding anything as it isn't used/evaluated in the first sample.

Answer (score 0):

Because Spring define Aspect using proxies. Using method1, When you call methodA from methodB, you are inside the proxy. Then, all aspects added by Spŕing is out off scope. You need apply PreAuthorize annotation to all methods that define your API.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but we can also use the proxy and call methodA, as in method 2. My question is which of the two methods is better and why?